# Return value from async Method

Tags: c#, web-services, async-await

I have asmx webservice and I am using in it in PCL, so all of us know that now PCL no longer supports asmx webservice, it supports wcf webservices. I somehow manage to call asmx webservice through PCL by using silverlight plugin. But it creates async method and converts WSDL to wcf.

Now problem is I need to return some values from webmethods which are now async method. If anybody know solution for this please help me.

I am using following code,

```
public class PerformLogIn
{
     string temp;
     public string checkTemp(string code)
     {
         ServiceReference1.WeatherSoapClient obj = new ServiceReference1.WeatherSoapClient(
                                    new BasicHttpBinding(),
                                    new EndpointAddress("http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"));

         obj.GetCityForecastByZIPCompleted+=getResult;
         obj.GetCityForecastByZIPAsync(code);

         return temp;
     }
     void getResult(Object sender,GetCityForecastByZIPCompletedEventArgs e)
     {
         string error = null;

         if (e.Error != null)
             error = e.Error.Message;
         else if (e.Cancelled)
             error = "cancelled";
         var result = e.Result; 
         temp=result.temprature;
     }
```

}

So when I run it, value of `temp` is null. When I debugged it, I found that when  `getResult` occures, it enters into `void getResult` by that time it has reached to `return` statement.

The problem here is, when `GetCityForecastByZIPAsync` method which is `async` gets called, it doesn't wait for others' operation to complete, it just finishes its execution and returns. Now being having a `webservice` which gets invoked only on occurrence of event `getResult`(in this case), invocation of event `getResult` (in this case) is based on network, server response which will have a little delay that we can't control. So till that time `GetCityForecastByZIPAsync` method finishes its execution. And after some time when `getResult` event occurs, it executes but does not return to the calling method viz. `checkTemp` method.

So how do I get data from  `getResult` event and put it back to `checkTemp` method so that I can use it for my purpose.

If anybody knows, please help me out.

Comment: We can't really help you out without knowing the public API for `sampleSoapClient`. But, at a first glance, it looks to me like you're mixing event-based asynchrony with task-based asynchrony, and you're not waiting for `AuthenticateUserLoginAsync` to complete.

Comment: @dcastro: Because of some reason I cant put `sampleSoapClient`. But I have put another example having exactly same behavior. So please help me out in according to code posted above.

Answer (score -2):

The two most obvious problems with your code are that a) you are subscribing your `getResult` event handler *after* you initiate the asynchronous operation, which means the operation could complete before you are set up to be notified of the completion, and b) your `checkTemp` method doesn't wait for the completion before it returns the result.

The first issue is easy to fix. Just reverse the order of the two statements, so that they look like this:

```
     obj.GetCityForecastByZIPCompleted += getResult;
     obj.GetCityForecastByZIPAsync(code);
```

Fixing the second part is harder to comment on, mainly because you haven't provided enough context in your question. If the `GetCityForecastByZIPAsync` method is actually a C# `async` method, then the best approach is to get rid of the `getResult` method altogether (as well as subscribing it to the `...Completed` event), and `await` the call to `GetCityForecastByZIPAsync`. Otherwise, the best approach is for `checkTemp` to not actually return the value, but rather for that method to be `void` and for your `getResult` method to handle whatever actually needs to happen when the operation completes (e.g. by invoking code that displays the result in the UI).

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I tried to add little more context. Please check and let me know if you know the solution.

Comment: I didn't find the additional description all that useful. What would really be needed is clearly stated documentation of the `WeatherSoapClient` and its `GetCityForecastByZIPAsync()` method. That said, assuming what you added is true and the method is a true `async` method, then read what I wrote in my original answer: "If the GetCityForecastByZIPAsync method is actually a C# async method, then the best approach is to get rid of the getResult method altogether (as well as subscribing it to the ...Completed event), and await the call to GetCityForecastByZIPAsync".

Comment: By using `SlSvcUtil` plugins I have generated WSDL of http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL to WCF service. may be you can have look on it. Thanx.